# NSDictionary With Integer Values

Tags: objective-c, int, nsdictionary

I'm working on a game with monsters. Each one has a list of stats that are all going to be ints. I can set up each stat as it's own variable but I'd prefer to keep them in an NSDictionary since they are all related. I'm running into a problem when I'm trying to change the value's of each stat.

**What I Have:**

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        stats = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              @"Attack",  0,
              @"Defense", 0,
              @"Special Attack", 0,
              @"Special Defense", 0,
              @"HP", 0, nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**What I want to do**

```
-(void) levelUp {
    self.level++;
    [self.stats objectForKey:@"Attack"] += (level * 5);
    [self.stats objectForKey:@"Defense"] += (level * 5);
    [self.stats objectForKey:@"Special Attack"] += (level * 5);
    [self.stats objectForKey:@"Special Defense"] += (level * 5);
    [self.stats objectForKey:@"HP"] += (level * 5);
}
```

**Error I'm Getting**

```
Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'id', which is not a constant size in non-fragile ABI
```

So it seems obvious to me that the reason I'm getting the problem is that I'm getting an object returned from objectForKey instead of an integer. So I tried to do the intValue method on the object I'm getting but that gave me another error, specifically:

```
Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an objective-c message not allowed
```

I'm out of ideas for how to fix this. Any help? Would it be better to just give up the idea to store them all together and just use an int property for each stat?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

1. You can only store objects, not primitives, within Cocoa collection classes, so to store numbers you need to use `NSNumber` objects.
2. You need to use an `NSMutableDictionary` if you wish to change the contents later.
3. Your call to `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` has the keys and values reversed.
4. Your `stats` object is not being retained, so it will be released next time round the run loop (if you're using manual reference counting, that is).

You want:

```
stats = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"Attack",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"Defense",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"Special Attack",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"Special Defense",
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"HP",
    nil] retain];
```

In order to change the values you need to create a new `NSNumber` object as they are immutable, so something like:

```
NSNumber *num = [stats objectForKey:@"Attack"];
NSNumber *newNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[num intValue] + (level * 5)];
[stats setObject:newNum forKey:@"Attack"];
```

All pretty tedious if you ask me; there must be an easier way, for example how about creating an Objective-C class to store and manipulate this stuff?

Comment: I don't have to worry about retaining if I'm using ARC right? Also you're right this does look a bit tedious... maybe I'll try a class instead.

Comment: @CaldwellYSR Yes, you are right - no need to worry about `retain` if you're using ARC.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I don't know why I didn't think of making them a class anyways. It will make alot of things easier in the long run.

Comment: @CaldwellYSR Yup; inheritance and encapsulation will pay dividends as well.

Answer (score 9):

`NSDictionary`s store `NSObject*`s.  In order to use them with integer values, you unfortunately need to use something like `NSNumber`.  So your initialization would look like:

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        stats = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              @"Attack",  [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
              @"Defense", [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
              @"Special Attack", [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
              @"Special Defense", [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
              @"HP", [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you would have to retrieve them as numbers:

```
NSNumber *atk = [self.stats objectForKey:@"Attack"];
int iAtk = [atk intValue];
[self.stats setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:iAtk] forKey:@"Attack"];
```

**EDIT**

Of course, in order to do this, `self.stats` needs to be an `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: Wow How did I completely forget that you can't change values without them being mutable. Once I retrieve the NSNumber will I be able to add an integer to that NSNumber?

Comment: The order of the values and keys in `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` is reversed and `stats` isn't being retained.

Answer (score 6):

Adapting @trojanfoe's answer for modern Objective-C with nice syntax sugar:

```
stats = [@{@"Attack"          : @0,
           @"Defense"         : @0,
           @"Special Attack"  : @0,
           @"Special Defense" : @0,
           @"HP"              : @0} mutableCopy];
```

And to update a value:

```
stats[@"Attack"] = @([stats[@"Attack"] intValue] + (level * 5));
```